# Nonrestrictive Clauses and Coordinating conjunction separating two independent clauses

Tags: commas, clauses, coordinating-conjunctions, non-restrictive

Quick, not so simple question.

I know that, if you join two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction (like "and"), you need a comma before the coordinating conjunction.

For example: I walked to the store, and I bought some cheese.

My question is if this holds up when you throw in a non-restrictive clause after the coordinating conjunction.

For example: I walked to the store, and, despite having plenty of cheese at home, I bought some cheese.

or

I walked to the store and, despite having plenty of cheese at home, I bought some cheese.

Based on a strict following of the rules, I feel like the first example is correct. But it sure does look ugly.

Comment: What you think you know is wrong. You *don't* need a comma in *I walked to the store and I bought some cheese.* It's a stylistic choice, and my guess is for that *exact* context, most people wouldn't include it. Nor would they introduce a marked pause there in the *spoken* version, which is the only reason for writing a comma in the first place. In the *despite having plenty of cheese at home* versions, that italicized text is a parenthetical / optional clause, which is normally "set off, delineated" by a matched pair of commas.

Comment: A comma is not required with a coordinator. In your last example many speakers would omit the comma after store, since the commas after "and" and "home" are sufficient to mark the PP "despite having plenty of cheese at home" as a supplement.

Comment: What makes it ugly is not doing this: I walked to the store. And despite having plenty of cheese at home, I bought some more. That is more elegant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Every source and handbook I come across lists this as a common rule. The fact that most people would not include the comma does not make the inclusion of the comma incorrect nor does it make the omission of the comma correct.

Comment: @Shane is there "correct" way to make an omelette? there are just different styles. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s10etP1p2bU

Comment: @Lambie ‘Elegant’ is a very subjective term. I find your suggestion horribly inelegant and would always correct it to a single sentence if proofreading.

Comment: Shane - I never said it was "incorrect" to include a comma in your example. It usually *wouldn't* be included in constructions like that - but like I said, ***it's a stylistic choice***. Any source telling you there's a "rule" that you *must* have a comma is ***wrong***.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Elegance is subjective, yes. So what? Parallelism does not require commas and no one seems to care.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that, if you join two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction (like "and"), you need a comma before the coordinating conjunction.
>
> For example: I walked to the store, and I bought some cheese.

You do not ***need*** a comma when using conjunctions to join clauses. Maybe, you could say, you definitely do for dependent clauses, but you certainly can get by without them - in formal writing - when joining ind. clauses. Even your example would be fine:

> I walked to the store and I bought some cheese.
>
> (Native speakers might drop the repeated subject and just have "*I walked to the store and bought some cheese*")

Commas are introduced as a matter of necessity with lists, though, so you may be thinking about the actions as a serial sequence of events. But that's unnecessary in your example.

Commas are *punctuation*, not **[grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar)**. Punctuation marks how the reader should approach or interpret text so that they have the same understanding when they read it that the author had when he wrote it. It is also used, along with constructions like **[meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(poetry))** used to help *speakers* when they are reading texts *aloud*.

Generally punctuation and grammar align very nicely and everyone's happy. But as you explore language as you have with your examples, I would say the best operating assumption for commas is that 1) *they mark a pause* (like a breath), and 2) they should not be *overused* or you break the cadence of the **[sentence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentence)**.

Returning to your examples:

> My question is if this holds up when you throw in a non-restrictive clause after the coordinating conjunction.
>
> For example: I walked to the store, and, despite having plenty of cheese at home, I bought some cheese.
>
> or
>
> **I walked to the store and, despite having plenty of cheese at home, I bought some cheese.**

I would go with the second form. It works like the dependent clause mention earlier; you are setting aside the dep. clause "*despite having plenty of cheese at home*" from the complex clause of the main sentence.

Good question. I suffered the angst of comma placement for years. It never really goes away =)

---

Edit: Exception cited by request, [NYT article from today](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/columbine-shooting-sol-pais.html):

> Before she was found, the authorities said **Ms. Pais had traveled to Denver and was considered armed and “extremely dangerous,”** leading to the decision to keep about half a million students home in two dozen school districts.
>
> Or, *Ms. Pais had traveled to the store and Ms. Pais was considered to have bought cheese*

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'd like to know where you are getting the idea that you do not need commas before coordinating conjunctions to join independent clauses. Every source/handbook I come across lists this as a common rule. You're correct that it does not impede meaning, but my job requires that I follow the rules.

Comment: i get paid 114K / year to write, only write. my job has no problems with my application and understanding of language. but im sure other writers who get paid more might disagree. language is alive

Comment: also people like me write the handbooks you reference lol

Comment: I think this answer is fine. That said, I would rewrite this sentence as I did in my comment below the question. It really annoys me when people downvote irresponsibly. Grghhh. :) Hey Carly, could you pass some along?

Comment: You didn't answer my question that I thought I politely posed, but thanks for the snark and taking the opportunity to drop in your salary. Your pay has nothing to do with whether or not you are correct here. Yes, language is alive. If that is the position of everyone here, I don't know why this board exists or why you would even bother to answer questions like these.

Comment: yes: I apologize for the snark. no: i did answer your question. maybe: if you consider money a metric as a rough proxy for experience or expertise. no: some others are nicer than me. some others are meaner. im here to explore language. you asserting that i am "wrong by every handbook" is not very nice either, when i went through the trouble of outlining my thought process...

Comment: All I was asking is if there is a documented exception to the rule (the question you did not answer). I did not mean to assert that you are wrong by every handbook (nor did I come close to doing so...). I appreciated you taking the time to answer, and I did not at all expect that things would turn this way. The internet is a strange place.

Comment: When there is parallelism, you do not need a comma. I went to the store and I bought three books. That is a stylistic writing rule.

Comment: Generally, no comma is required with a coordinator.

Comment: I don't even know if I should reengage, but your example doesn't line up with what I was asking about. "was considered armed and 'extremely dangerous'" is not an independent clause, so I would not expect to see a comma before the coordinating conjunction. In any case, AP style has its own set of rules (omission of the serial comma comes immediately to mind), but I work in the academic world, so the rules cited by Shoe (below) are what I go by.

Comment: I'd go more into what I do and why this is important to me, but I'm afraid that Carly and I may work in the same circle or have overlapping circles. I'm slightly kicking myself for posting this with my first name. After this, I guess I will be ever skeptical of anyone I come across named Carly, and Carly will have a sneaking suspicion that anyone named Shane is a moron who is over concerned with comma usage.

Comment: To those of you criticizing my example: I made it simple for a reason. Yes, I would never actually write my particular example. I was just coming up with two very simple independent clauses and combining them with a coordinating conjunction. I'm glad that Shoe took the time to post the several examples of this rule's existence, and I am still surprised with the self-assured manner with which several of you told me I was flat out wrong.

Comment: You did not just post that. Your question was about adding a phrase into the mix and then wondering about commas. fyi, correlative clauses and clauses joined by a simple and are different. Parallel structure in English does not require commas: I went to the store and I bought some cheese. No comma.

Comment: @lambie The OWL at Purdue says otherwise. Here is one of their example sentences: The game was over, but the crowd refused to leave.

This sentence has parallel structure and a comma before the coordinating conjunction. This is a hard rule according to the Online Writing Lab at Purdue (and many other sources). I recognize that not everyone follows this rule, but my work requires that I do.

Comment: @Shane That is a correlative conjunction. The game was over and the crowd refused to leave.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in addition to Carly's answer. I am addressing this from a style point of view. Style is somewhat subjective though parallelism can be one of its elements.

> Parallelism:
>
> - I walked to the store and I bought some cheese. [parallel]
> - I walked to the store and bought some cheese. [reduced for style by removing the repetition of the pronoun, but also parallel]

Parallel structure as given about where two sentences are joined by "and" do no required a comma. They are not correlative structures. [see link]

[Compare parallel structure or correlative structure](https://www.evergreen.edu/sites/default/files/writingcenter/handouts/grammar/parallel.pdf)

Anything introduced after this such as a modifying phrase, would require being set off by commas, to wit:

> - I walked to the store and, after thinking about it, I bought some cheese.

Since a phrase has been introduced before the second SVP (subject, verb, predicate), a comma is required just at it would be here (regardless of whether the sentence is compound/complex or not, as above):

> > - After thinking about it, I bought some cheese. [comma required for a preposition plus a gerund when pre-positioned]
> >       Compare:
> > - I bought some cheese after thinking about it. [no comma required]
>
> Awkwardness reduction:

ORIGINAL: 
 I walked to the store and, after thinking about it, bought (or I bought) some cheese.

The sentence above is not very elegant. I would call it clunky.  It can be improved in terms of flow by doing this:

REWRITE: 
I walked to the store. And after thinking about it, I bought some cheese.

> Suggestion: I suggest reading it out loud. Style is indeed subjective.
>   In poetic terms (sound and rhythm), it can be argued that the prosody
>   of the  rewrite sounds better than the example above it. Perhaps the
>   reason for this is that the thinking occurs after reaching the store.
>   It comes prior to the act of buying cheese and breaks the the plodding
>   nature of using just a single sentence.

Finally, I have assumed - perhaps totally inaccurately - that these sentences would appear within a large context.

> I walked to the store. And after thinking about it, I bought some
>   cheese. That's when the realization hit me [etc.]

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of evidence in support of the OP's claim that there exists the 'rule' *if you join two independent clauses with a coordinating conjunction (like "and"), you need a comma before the coordinating conjunction*. For example:

> Use commas to separate independent clauses when they are joined by any
>   of these seven coordinating conjunctions: *and, but, for, or, nor, so,
>   yet*. ([Owl at Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html))
>
> ...the comma separates coordinated main clauses (*Garner's Modern
>   American Usage*, p676)
>
> When independent clauses are joined by *and, but, for, or, nor, so,
>   yet*, or any other conjunction, a comma usually precedes the
>   conjunction. (*The Chicago Manual of Style 16th edition, section 6.28*)

Nevertheless many writers do not feel compelled to follow this style advice, particularly on the British side of the Atlantic. Steven Pinker in *The Sense of Style* (p283) has a good introductory passage on the issue:

> The problem for the writer is that punctuation indicates prosody in
>   some places, syntax in others, and neither of them consistently
>   anywhere. After centuries of chaos, the rules of punctuation began to
>   settle down only a bit more than a century ago, and even today the
>   rules differ on the two sides of the Atlantic and from one publication
>   to another. The rules, moreover, are subject to changes in fashion,
>   including an ongoing trend to reduce all punctuation to the bare
>   minimum. They fill scores of pages in reference manuals, and no one
>   but a professional copy-editor knows them all. Even the sticklers
>   can't agree on how to stickle.

In order to remove multiple commas, which can make text clunky to read and are problematic in the OP's second sentence, it can be useful to do some reordering. For example, a little tweaking can produce a version that requires no commas at all:

> *Original*: I walked to the store, and, despite having plenty of cheese
>   at home, I bought some cheese.
>
> *Revision*: I walked to the store and bought some cheese despite having
>   plenty at home.

As a British English speaker who tends towards *bare minimum* punctuation this would be my preferred version in what appears to be an informal context. In a similar sentence structure in more formal writing I would put a comma after *cheese*.

Comment: I can't see that you explicitly make the point, but to my mind the only significantly "unbreakable" rule relating to your examples is that the parenthetical  clause *despite having plenty of cheese at home* requires an "all or nothing" approach. Either it has to be set off within a "matched pair" of commas, or none at all (to me, it's *never* correct to have a solitary comma before or after it, except if that clause comes at the end or at the beginning of a sentence).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I agree with '_two or none_' for parenthetical clauses such as the one in question or for non-restrictive relative clauses. I would say that my only unbreakable rule regarding commas is to put one in if the sentence might otherwise be misunderstood: _Let's eat Grandma!_ etc.

Comment: Your first set of examples are not imperative and use terms like "usually", which leaves it open for interpretation, I would say. Excellent examples.

Comment: @Carly. Well spotted! Both Garner and the Chicago say that it's ok to omit the comma if the first clause is short or the subject is the same in both clauses but dropped in the second clause (as you stated in your answer). I should add that the Grandma example is from Pinker.

Comment: Are only exactly _two_ independent clauses joined by _comma_ plus _coordinating conjunction_, or can any number of independent clauses be joined similarly too? And can they be separated like in lists, i.e., with the last pair of clauses separated by _,_ + _coordinating conjunction_ and the rest only by a comma)?

Comment: @Mr Reality. You can string as many independent clauses together as you want but you will soon end up with a _rambling sentence_, which is considered poor style: https://www.thoughtco.com/rambling-and-run-on-sentences-1857155

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence, **I walked to the store, and, despite having plenty of cheese, I bought some cheese.** is a compound complex sentence with two independent clauses and a dependent clause.

It can correctly be punctuated as:

***I walked to the store, and despite having plenty of cheese, I bought some cheese.***

Or,

***Despite having plenty of cheese, I walked to the store, and I bought some cheese.***

Details and more examples are [here](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sentences.htm).

Comment: I think the vast majority of writers would enclose the parenthetical clause *despite having plenty of cheese* in commas. But whether that's present or not, most *wouldn't* include (yet another) comma after ***and***.